# Serialization with c#, deserialization with Ruby, is it possible?

Tags: c#, ruby, serialization, deserialization

Is there are way to serialize an object to a file using C#, and then later, deserialize it from another application I've built using the Ruby language?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you serialize it to XML there should not be a problem to deserialize it in Ruby. Google can point you to a gem to handle it.

If you use IronRuby, it usea the same .NET assemblies as c#. if so the process should (in theory) be transparant then.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.

That's what it's for, I'm sure both languages can read and write it.

EDIT: Two things I found in two seconds to get you started: [Ruby JSON library](http://flori.github.com/json/) and [JSON .NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)